Assigning to model in controller method does nothing
I want to assign values to my Item model right before saving it in the create method of my ItemsController that handles POST requests. But it seems like nothing happens.
# app/models/item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list
  ...

  attr_accessor :list_id, :user_id # this should allow me to assign to fields directly
end

# app/controllers/items_controller.rb
  # POST /items or /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params) # Original generated code
    @item.list_id = 1 # I am assigning a value here
    @item.user_id = session[:user_id] # and here

    logger.debug session[:user_id] # => 1
    logger.debug @item # => #<Item id: nil, name: "sad", quantity: 1, user_id: nil, list_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    ...
  end

Why are @item.user_id and @item.list_id still showing up as nil just after the assignment?

Remove this:
attr_accessor :list_id, :user_id # this should allow me to assign to fields directly

You can already assign list_id and user_id by default. Rails creates readers and writers for every column in your tables which you're overwriting with your own attribute accessors. There is a lot more logic behind attributes than a simple instance variable assignment.

It might be worth noting that unlike a plain Ruby class, ActiveRecord doesn't store the model's attributes in separate instance variables, i.e. there's no @list_id or @user_id.

You're making the classic beginner misstake of conflating instance variables and ActiveRecord/ActiveModel attributes.
What attr_accessor :list_id, :user_id does is deefine simple setters and getter methods for the listed instance variables. Which is great for simple plain old Ruby classes but it's not how ActiveRecord works.
Instead ActiveRecord queries the database for the table metadata that describes the schema and uses that to create setters and getters via metaprogramming. These setters do not store each attribute in a single instance variable - rather each attribute is stored in a hash containing all the attributes as well as the attribute before typecasting and more.
When you use attr_accessor :list_id, :user_id you're clobbering those setters so the actual attribute stored in the hash that ActiveRecord stores in the database is never written and its not marked as dirty which causes ActiveRecord to persist it. That's why you get a nil when the model is read back from the database.
In Rails models you should pretty much never use attr_accessor (or the other Ruby accessor macros). For database columns YAGNI and if you need an attribute that's not backed by a database column use the ActiveModel::Attributes API instead.
